# Javascript image change: Fade

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay. I have got this much regarding code. It changes the background every 5 seconds, but I don't have the knowledge to be able to make it fade.

I want to be able to make the images crossfade (As one fades out, the next fades in). Can I please be pointed in the correct direction as how I would do this? I'm trying to learn off of W3 (as with everything else) but to no avail, so I come here seeking knowledge.

My ability to take examples and intergrate it into my own work isn't exactly great, but I'll try my best. Thanks for any support

```
var i=0;
var background-src=[
    "url(http://i.imgur.com/lfprcuC.jpg)",
    "url(http://hdwallpaperhub.net/wallpapers/l/1920x1080/84/garrys_mod_half_life_2_1920x1080_83543.jpg)"
    ]

function background-content() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery('#content').css('background-image', background-src[i]);
        i++;
        if(i==background-src.length) i=0;
        background-content();
    }, 5000);
}
background-content();
```

Just as a side ask, would anyone be able to show me how to make each image slowly zoom? For example, how the Garry's Mod Main Menu (for those who are familiar) zooms in on an image before it changes

Many thanks (Am still trying to learn, but its just not working ._.)

Comment: Care. You can't use operators in variable names

Comment: Yes, this fixed everything